# Entity isn't translating with a2lix bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a symfony2 project and I got a class that has two fields that can be translated. For the form I use bundle [a2lix for symfony2 version 2.2](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle)

That part is working ok, the entity and the correspondent entityTranslator are populated in database. But the problem is when I try to show the entity content, those fields always show with the default locale instead of the actual locale.

My entity:

```
 /**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ecm_product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation")
 */
 class Product{

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
    * @Gedmo\Translatable
    */
    protected $name;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    protected $slug;

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
    * @Gedmo\Translatable
    */
    protected $description;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation",
     *  mappedBy="object",
     *  cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     * @Assert\Valid(deep = true)
     */
     private $translations;


    public function getTranslations() {
       return $this->translations;
    }

    public function setTranslations($translations) {
       foreach ($translations as $translation) {
          $translation->setObject($this);
       }

      $this->translations = $translations;
      return $this;
    }

    /**
   * Remove translation
   *
   * @param Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation $translation
   */
   public function removeTranslation(Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation $translation)
   {
      if ($this->translations->contains($translation)) {
          $this->translations->removeElement($translation);
      }
   }


   /**
    * Add translation
    *
    * @param Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation $translation
    * @return PrivacyPolicy
    */
    public function addTranslation(Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation $translation)
    {
       if (!$this->translations->contains($translation)) {
          $this->translations[] = $translation;
          $translation->setObject($this);
       }

       return $this;
   }


}
```

My entityTranslation:

```
/**
 * Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation.php

 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ecm_product_translations",
 *   uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="lookup_unique_idx", columns={
 *     "locale", "object_id", "field"
 *   })}
 * )
 */
class ProductTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Product", inversedBy="translations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $object;

    public function getObject() {
        return $this->object;
    }

    public function setObject($object) {
        $this->object = $object;
    }
}
```

And in my repositories I always add this line:

```
$qb->getQuery()->setHint(
                    \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
                    'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
            );
```

But my entity isn't translated :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, you need to define a listener also in configs, I had it but only for one of the entity manager (I've got 2) and that's why it wasn't translating. Here's the code for anyone who may need:

```
services:
    gedmo.listener.translatable:
        class: Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: client }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]
            - [ setDefaultLocale, [ %locale% ] ]
            - [ setTranslationFallback, [ true ] ]
            - [ setPersistDefaultLocaleTranslation, [false] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck that $request->getLocale() is returning the correct locale when you request the page. 
Your code seems correct, but hard to say without all the code in the product entity (like the missing property $translations).

You could try to add the following code to your Product entity to see if it helps:

```
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;


class Product implements Translatable {

    protected $locale;

   /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation", 
     *     mappedBy="object", 
     * )
     */
    protected $translations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ....


    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }


}
```

Comment: I got the locale defined in my ProductTranslation (I supose it comes from the abstract class I'm extending but my correspondent table has the locale, object_id, field and the content). I added to my question the translations properties, hope it helps :)